# Wrong Remmina Folder Colors

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, remmina

I installed and used Remmina through `apt` as an SSH organizer on Ubuntu 18.04. However, suddenly today all of the directory colors change to black whenever I switch to the dark terminal (blue for a white terminal).

For a quick update: the original colors (Linux, Tango, Xterm,...) work fine.

I have tried to update the Remmina colors through the UI, but everything changes except the directories.

[image: Example]

It applies to any connection I make, so I am quite sure that is a Remmina problem. When I check at debug console, it yields `(remmina:5815): Vte-CRITICAL **: 12:36:00.368: void vte_terminal_set_colors(VteTerminal*, const GdkRGBA*, const GdkRGBA*, const GdkRGBA*, gsize): assertion 'valid_color(&palette[i])' failed`  whenever I opened a custom color palette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error, it seems like the color configuration has broken. Therefore, I check the `remmina.pref` in `~/.local/share/remmina` and the one at `~.config/remmina`. I noticed there is a color mismatch, I have no idea why. Just replace the 'ssh_colors' and everything back to normal B)